# ListView datasource is not updating - React-Native

Tags: android, listview, react-native, datasource

I'm trying to update listview from a function, But currently it is not updating, Here is the complete source code.

Please also mention that what I am doing wrong

```
     import React, { Component } from 'react';
     import {
       AppRegistry,
       ListView,
       TextView,
       Text,
       View
     } from 'react-native';


     const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 != row2 });

     var myarray = [];
     export default class filesix extends Component {
       constructor() {
         super();
         this.state = {
           dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(myarray),
         };
         console.log(`ds const =${myarray}`);
       }


       componentDidMount() {
         myarray = ['11', '22'];
         console.log(myarray);
         this.setState = ({
           datasource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(myarray),
         });
         this.prepareDataSource();
         console.log('this componentDidMount');
       }

       prepareDataSource() {    
         myarray = ['11', '22'];
         console.log(myarray);
       }

       renderRow(rowData) {
         return <Text>{JSON.stringify(rowData)}</Text>
       }

       render() {
         return (
           <View style={{ flex: 1, borderWidth: 2 }}>
             <ListView
               enableEmptySections={true}
               dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
               renderRow={this.renderRow}
             />
           </View>
         );
       }
     }

     AppRegistry.registerComponent('filesix', () => filesix);
```

I already spent my whole day to update the values, but no luck, Please correct my understanding.

Comment: What is not being updated? Is it rendering those two rows?

Comment: no it's not rendering two rows

Answer (score 1):

Your `componentDidMount` has a typo.  It's setting state on `datasource` but your ListView is using `dataSource`.

Comment: Adding something else more would be redundant.